# how to achieve facebook mobile site buttons menu scroll effect?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, css-float

When you open the facebook mobile site from a mobile device with a profile with a timeline, there is menu with items such as: "About","Photos", "Freinds" ,"Subscription" ,"Map", ...

You can slide the menu items on your mobile device.

How can I do this with html, css, js to works with all devices?

[Sample](http://m.facebook.com/apps/the-farmer?fb_source=search&ref=search#!/jackie.yaacov?__user=625134695)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's greate tutorial [Creating a Mobile Touch Slide Panel with JQuery](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/).
Source code also available on github - [jstouchslide](https://github.com/zgrossbart/jstouchslide).